# Does Emissary of Redemption reflect damage after it applies resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, paladin, damage-resistance

The [Oath of Redemption paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#OathofRedemption) has the 20th-level feature Emissary of Redemption (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 39):

> #### Emissary of Redemption
>
> At 20th level, you become an Avatar of Peace, which gives you two benefits:
>
> - You have resistance to all damage dealt by other creatures (their attacks, spells, and other effects).
> - Whenever a creature hits you with an attack, it takes radiant damage equal to half the damage you take from the attack.

It states that you reflect half the damage you *take* so it seems that he should take 1/4 of the total attack. I'm not aware of any rule about *when* the resistance applies.

**Does Emissary of Redemption reflect damage before or after it applies resistance?**

(I'm pretty sure it should be 1/4, just because it would be too strong otherwise, and my master will probably be using it this way too.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes, it's 1/4

You ask "when the resistance applies". The PHB answers that:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

Obviously this is *before* you **take** damage. As you mentioned yourself, the wording is very clear

> half the **damage you take** from the attack.

If you are unsure about what is the "damage taken", it's defined in the Damage and Healing subsection:

> Whenever a creature takes damage, that damage is subtracted from its Hit Points.

This means the "damage you take" is exactly how many Hit Points you reduced, i.e., after the resistance was applied.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave a very precise answer. What I was missing was exactly that one rule about damage resistance, now i have no doubt.

Comment: @YED-YellowEndlessDog It seems a little awkward to say that as the person that gave the answer, but if you think this answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the mark under the downvote button in the left. It's recommended that you wait 24h before doing so, though, so everyone in different time zones has a chance to answer.

Answer (score 0):

1/2 damage of rolled+modifiers is the Correct answer. Responses here conflate damage dealt and taken. These are distinctly different.
Emmissary of Redemption as relevant states "Whenever a creature damages you, it takes radiant damage equal to half the amount it dealt to you."
Damage in combat is:

1. damage dealt, total dice roll plus modifiers (including crit)
2. resistance and vulnerability apply
3. damage taken.

Comment: Strange... the question seems to be quoting from something, but yours seems to be the correct quote. Do you know if it was revised?

Comment: I'm not certain your order of operations is correct; do you have any citations for it? I would think that, for instance, Vampiric Touch would heal less if the target resists necrotic damage, but it seems you think it will heal about 5 damage even if the target is immune.